# button opening another page

Tags: php, html

I was wondering if it was possible to make this button when i click on it to transfer me on for example

mytickets.php, now i'm using forms, but they dont work on my web server, it just reloads the page, and i know i can use form but there are 2 buttons

```
<div id="container">
<br>
<div class="transbox">

<?php
    session_start();
    require('konektor.php');

    if(!(isset($_SESSION['login_user']) && $_SESSION['login_user'] != '')){

        header ("Location: index.php");
    }
    else
    {
    if (isset($_POST['otvoritiket']))
    {
        header("location: novitiket.php");
    }
    if (isset($_POST['pogledajarhivu']))
    {
        header("location: arhiviranitiketi.php");
    }

    $username = $_SESSION['login_user'];
    $username=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $username);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM Tiketi WHERE Autor='$username' AND `Arhiviran` = '0'";

    if ($result = $con->query($query)) 
    {
        echo '
        <table id="tfhover" class="tftable" border="1">
           <th>ID Tiketa</th>
            <th>Autor</th>
            <th>Naslov</th>
            <th>Kategorija</th>
            <th>Datum</th>
        ';
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['ID'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['Autor'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td><a href="viewticket.php?ticketid='. $row['ID'] .'">'. $row['Naslov'] .'</a></td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['Kategorija'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['Datum'] . '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        $result->free();
    }
    }
    mysqli_close($con); 
?>

</table>

</div>

<form action="" method="post">
<center>
<button type="submit" name = "otvoritiket" class="btn green uppercase">Otvori tiket</button> 
<button type="submit" name = "pogledajarhivu" class="btn green uppercase">Arhivirani tiketi</button>
</center><br>
</form>


</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes. It's possible.

Comment: *"but they dont work on my web server"* - Define "don't work".

Comment: When i press the button it just reload my web page,
for example
 if (isset($_POST['otvoritiket']))
 {
  header("location: novitiket.php");
 }

Comment: well you have the php, we don't.

Comment: please don't drop code in comments everywhere. That needs to be inside your question and as an edit http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39171283/edit

Comment: sorry, edited, im kinda new here.

Comment: well you're outputting before header, for one thing. Check for errors and you'll see. Your headers also need exits.

Comment: you also have no name attribute matching `pogledajarhivu` so the question's unclear at this point. It's failing for a few reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify page name in action attribute of form tag when button is clicked. Like this

```
<form action="page-after-button-click.php" method="post">
```

or you can apply click even if you are using jQuery.

```
    $("button").click(function() {
        //Do something here 
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use code below which sends form to yourpagehere.php

```
<form action="yourpagehere.php">
[form]
<button type="submit" name = "otvoritiket" class="btn green uppercase">Posalji odgovor</button>
</form>
```

Or you can use JS. Then you should bind onclick action to this button to change document location in browser, but without more js code it don't send form content to another page.

Comment: `<form action="yourpagehere.php">` guess what method that defaults to? Certainly not "post".

Comment: it could be one of POST/GET of course, but as you can see Cadilab knows how to use this argument

Comment: Did you not see the code they added in the question now? `$_POST` and many of them. FYI: `<form action="yourpagehere.php">` is equal to doing `<form action="yourpagehere.php" method="get">` which in turn will fail.

Answer (score -2):

There is topic for wondering there.
Just edit you code as follows:

```
<form action="mytickets.php" method="post">
```

If you mytickets.php file is exists in same folder where is your form file exist.

The specify the folder name with mytickets.php file

Like as

```
<form action="yourfolder/mytickets.php" method="post">
```

Or

```
<form action="yourfolder/anotherfolder/mytickets.php" method="post">
```

Comment: that has nothing to do with the problem. Are people not paying attention at all?

Comment: btw, why are you trying to edit this guy's answer? http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13475933 you realize that is considered as vandalism.